# Git clone with oauth token from passport.js (Github)

Tags: git, github, oauth

I use passport.js to log a user into my app. When passport finishes auth, I am able to get the github access token. I then take that access token and try to clone a private repo of the user. I am NOT using a personal access token. Is there a way to git clone a private repo with an oauth access token received from passport.js?

Passport login:

```
authGithub: (req, res)=>{
    passport.authorize('github', {scope : ['user:email','repo'], accessType: 'offline', approvalPrompt: 'force'})(req, res)
  }

passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
  clientID: config.custom.githubAuth.clientId,
  clientSecret: config.custom.githubAuth.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: config.custom.githubAuth.callbackUrl
},
  ((accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, cb) => {
    profile.githubAccessToken = accessToken
    profile.githubRefreshToken = refreshToken
    return cb(null, profile);
  })
));
```

From there, I have tried these on command line:

```
➜  Code git clone https://XXX@github.com/joncodo/react-analysis-sample
Cloning into 'react-analysis-sample'...
fatal: unable to look up XXX@github.com (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
➜  Code git clone https://XXX:x-oauth-basic@github.com/joncodo/react-analysis-sample
Cloning into 'react-analysis-sample'...
fatal: unable to look up XXX:x-oauth-basic@github.com (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
➜  Code git clone https://joncodo:XXX@github.com/joncodo/react-analysis-sample foo2
Cloning into 'foo2'...
fatal: unable to look up joncodo:XXX@github.com (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

➜  Code mv ~/.ssh ~/.ssh_old
➜  Code git clone https://github.com/joncodo/react-analysis-sample foo
Cloning into 'foo'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.112.3)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:XXX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```